# Is there any alternative which can be used like Tcategorybuttons in delphi firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am new to delphi. I have developed one application in which
Left side I have category buttons and right side I have put a panel and based on the button clicked I am docking the relevant form on the panel.

Now I want to implement same type of menu nav style in Delphi fire monkey UI for desktop, but I cant find category buttons in firemonkey..Please suggest how can I achieve the same kind of menu bar or make some good navigation bar in fm..

Comment: A listview with custom items.

Comment: @Ken White Thanks a lot..!!.used a Listbox and added metropolisListboxItem to it.

Answer (score 0):

TMultiView. For details see [Samples folder]\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\Windows10NavigationPane\NavigationPaneDemo.dproj